# Couldnt find my destination on Android

Tags: android, gps

Hey, here is my I code, my app stil looks in the same default location, I searched but I couldnt find any solution plz help,

```
import java.util.List;


import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory; 
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener     
{    
    MapView mapView;
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    String coordinates[] = {"41.00527", "28.97696"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
    p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setCenter(p);
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(13);

    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
    mc = mapView.getController();

    // Getting locationManager and reflecting changes over map if distance travel by
    // user is greater than 500m from current location.

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
    Location currentLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();  
    lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();

    //---Add a location marker---
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay); 




    mapView.invalidate();


}
   @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            String currentLocation = "Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng;
            txted.setText(currentLocation);
            p = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(p);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */




    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
        boolean shadow, long when) 
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);            
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
            return true;
        }
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the code

```
MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
```

to `public void onLocationChanged(Location location)` also

Comment: what was the exception. can you post the log

Comment: I think I couldnt take new destination normally it shows always same start point and then I added the code parts that above and my app doesnt work: tha application has stopped unexpectedly, plz try again later...

Comment: not worth for write it: java socket exception. Can you give any advice about the take current position, do I have to change my onLocationChanged method?

Comment: why not try the `MyLocationOverlay`. It is meant to show your currentlocation on map. For reference see this http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html